# Field accessors as functions in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

Is there a way to convert field accessors to functions? I was really surprised when I tried to do this

```
(map .x [o1 o2])
```

but instead had to do this

```
(defn x [o] (.x o))
(map x [o1 o2])
```

which seems rather unnecessary. Is there a way to have this function created for you?

Comment: It's necessary because fields are not first class Objects in the jvm, so they can't be supplied as an argument to a function. In order to automatically make a function, you would want to know which class the accessor was going to be applied to at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own wee macro to generate the anonymous function:

```
(defmacro field [m] `(fn [x#] (. x# ~m)))
```

Then, for example,

```
((field x) (java.awt.Point. 3 5))
;3
```

Comment: Thanks! I've never written a macro. This should be standard.

Answer (score 7):

Use an anonymous `fn`

```
(map #(.x %) [o1 o2])
(map (fn [o] (.x o)) [o1 o2])
```

<strike>Or [memfn](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/memfn) - I've read an anonymous `fn` is preferred over this. I'll try to find the article.</strike>

```
(map (memfn x) [o1 o2])
```

**Edit**: Stu Halloway has [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/ONk1Kxycx1I/PHYmbnWetjQJ) to say about `memfn`

Comment: In memfn I get 'No matching method found: x for class ...'

Comment: Also "x" is a field not a method.

Comment: @CristianGarcia I didn't notice that. Sorry!